# Are Force Ghosts only visible to those who interacted with them in real life?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jedi, force-ghost

So, I was marathoning all 9 Star Wars movies again because.... well, why wouldn't I right?

I came across something I never thought of before.

The force ghosts that we see in the movies only appear to those who knew them in real life, and never appear to those who didn't.

So:

- Obi-wan is told that he would be able to communicate to **Qui-gon**, but Qui-gon never appeared to Luke or Rey.
- **Obi-wan** and **Yoda** both appear to Luke, but they didn't appear to Rey. Even when Yoda talks to Luke (Last Jedi) he doesn't talk to Rey.
- Anakin appears to Luke at the end of RotJ, but he never appears to Rey.
- **Luke** and **Leia** are the only ones who appear to Rey - they are also the only two she's met.

Are Force Ghosts only able to appear to those who interacted with them in real life? Is there anything to back this up, or to disprove it?

If not, it just seems that the whole Jedi Council could have gathered with Rey and discussed how to defeat grandpa.

Comment: Yoda appears to Ezra and they never met

Comment: Only a very small number of Jedi learned (from Qui-Gon) how to become ghosts and only those who're powerful in the Force can see them.

Comment: @NKCampbell Yoda was not a ghost when he interacted with Ezra

Comment: @Valorum And yet, as much as they teased it, Qui-Gon never actually appeared as a ghost, even though he supposedly was the first to learn how to do it.  I'm guessing Liam Neeson was not interested or just too expensive to hire for even a brief cameo when they filmed Episode III?

Comment: certain point of view @RogueJedi - he's a vision appearing to somebody he hasn't met :)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - It was explained that although he'd worked out how to preserve himself, he hadn't worked out how to go full ghost. It was only under the tutelage of Qui-Gon that Yoda and Ben Kenobi discovered how to do it properly.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman There's a deleted scene from ROTS where Yoda and Qui-Gon have a brief voice conversation, but it was cut from the final film (maybe because Yoda and Obi-Wan's conversation immediately after covers the same points).

Comment: In the James Kahn RotJ novelization they appear only to Luke and it is hinted that they are only an illusion in any case ("Luke thought he saw faces dancing—Yoda, Ben; was it his father? He drew away from his companions, to try to see what the faces were saying; they were ephemeral, and spoke only to the shadows of the flames, and then disappeared altogether.") This is contradicted by basically everything else, so I mention it just as a fun fact.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman He does in *The Clone Wars*. There's an arc in season 6 that tells the tale of Yoda learning of the whole Force ghost shtick from Qui-Gon's disembodied voice, and ultimately seeing his ghost. It suggests a learned ability, though it could just be knowing of the mere possibility of seeing Force ghosts.

Answer (score 18):

**No. They can appear to whomever they want (need) to**

Disembodied voices are Force ghosts too, and Rey interacted with at least:
Obi-Wan Kenobi,
Anakin Skywalker,
Ahsoka Tano,
Kanan Jarrus,
Luminara Unduli,
Qui-Gon Jinn,
Aayla Secura,
Mace Windu,
Adi Gallia, and
Yoda.

Rey did not meet a single one of them. She heard Luke too, but had met him while he was with body, reinforcing that Force ghosts can also interact with people they already knew.

Comment: *whomever they want (need) to* - As long as that person is a powerful and trained Force user?

Comment: I don’t think there is any indication which necessarily associates the ghost’s appearances to their intended target’s perceived power levels. I think such a hypothesis is an anathema to Yoda’s ESB teaching any way; “powerful?” Judge them by their size, would you?

Comment: Well, the fact that neither Han nor Leia can see Anakin, Ben and Yoda would certainly suggest that there's selective viewing going on.

Comment: Leia is The Other Hope (tm), though. And Han is a Force also-ran, so I think nether confirms or denies any hard or fast rule?

Comment: Han has almost zero Force powers (canonically) and Leia is untrained. Note that Luke can only see Ben once he's started to access the Force and meditate.

Comment: But Leia is “powerful.” Is seeing any better than hearing? It seems like all the important interaction occurs through words imparted rather than seeing holographic like images fake interacting with real world chairs.

Comment: As the question is worded to specifically say "visible," does this actually answer it?

Comment: @Valorum "*Leia is untrained*" - according to Episode 9, Luke did train her as a Jedi. She just didn't finish the training.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Presumably Valorum meant *at that point*, in the scene near the end of RoTJ where force ghosts appear as those 3 main characters are together.  (I think.)  The scene where the updated version added a force-ghost Anakin that wasn't there in the original version.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, yes, I missed the context, thanks

Comment: @PeterCordes Anakin was there at the end of *Return of the Jedi*, it was just a different actor, I believe the same that plays Vader unmasked earlier. The oddity of that scene is more that they're just hanging there like a trouple of Force ghost pals, rather than delivering some much-needed wisdom to the heroes.

Comment: It’s not odd. Yoda’s marshmallow & s’mores nights with the Ewoks is the most frequent Force ghost manifestations.

Comment: That's an interesting answer, but if we were to narrow it down to the "visible" manifestation of Force Ghosts. Rey heard the voices, but the only "visible" ones were Luke and Leia at the end. So it seems you can only "see" those you know.
(of course, out of universe, it would be veeery expensive bringing all the original actors for this one scene right?)

Answer (score 4):

**Legends answer: Definitely not**

Force ghosts are much more common in Legends media (mainly due to the rules not really being established until *Revenge of the Sith*) and appear to strangers on many occasions. For example, the plot of [*Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Knight:_Dark_Forces_II) is kicked off when Jedi Master Qu Rahn's spirit appears in a dream to Kyle Katarn, who he'd never met in life:

[image: Screenshot of Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II showing Qu Rahn's spirit]

Sith spirits, while technically not "Force ghosts" in the same sense, were also able to appear to complete strangers. For example, in *Knights of the Old Republic*, the player can meet the spirit of Ajunta Pall, who died around 3,000 years earlier.

As to whether Force ghosts or spirits could appear to non-Force-sensitives, it appears that they couldn't. In [*Star Wars Infinities: A New Hope*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Infinities:_A_New_Hope), Obi-Wan's ghost appears to Luke with Han present, but Han can't see him:

[image: Panel from Star Wars Infinities: A New Hope. Ben's ghost is saying "Luke! Don't give in to your Anger!", Luke is yelling "Ben!", and Han is saying "Ben? You are nuts!"]

However, this is an explicitly non-canon source. In *Knights of the Old Republic*, non-Force-sensitive party members seem able to interact with Sith spirits, although this may be a game mechanic or difference with Sith spirits.

Comment: Sith Spirits are, of course, not Force ghosts. Sith can't have ghosts because their Force practices prevent their survival after death.

Comment: @Valorum "survival after death." That cracked me up.

Comment: @formicini - Not survival as in "not dying", I might add.

Comment: In SWTOR, there’s a crapload of Sith Force-powered “apparitions.” Horak-Mul, et. al. is example from Inquisitor quest on Hoth who found a way to bind Sith ghosts to people. Kalatosh Zavros & Darth Andru are other SWTOR Sith typically identified as Force Ghosts